# Meteor accounts-ui forgotpassword from not defined

Tags: meteor, forgot-password

I am meteor with

```
accounts-password 
and accounts-ui
```

I have setup my Accounts.templates so that I can receive active e-mails,
but when I am using accounts-ui forgto password i got 'from undefined'
I am not so sure that  Accounts.templates .from attribute is the one I need to work with

```
I20150617-14:36:42.009(-7)? Exception while invoking method     
forgotPassword' TypeError: Cannot read property 'from' of undefined
I20150617-14:36:42.009(-7)?at Object.Accounts.sendResetPasswordEmail (packages/accounts-password/password_server.js:406:1)
I20150617-14:36:42.009(-7)?     at [object Object].Meteor.methods.forgotPassword (packages/accounts-password/password_server.js:365:1)
I20150617-14:36:42.009(-7)?     at maybeAuditArgumentChecks (packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:1617:1)
I20150617-14:36:42.009(-7)?     at packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:648:1
I20150617-14:36:42.009(-7)?     at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56:1)
I20150617-14:36:42.009(-7)?     at packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:647:1
I20150617-14:36:42.009(-7)?     at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56:1)
I20150617-14:36:42.009(-7)?     at [object Object]._.extend.protocol_handlers.method (packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:646:1)
I20150617-14:36:42.009(-7)?     at packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:546:1
```

can some one help me solve this?
Sorry for the mess format I am new with formatting 
thanks a lot

```
Accounts.emailTemplates = {
  from: " Meteor Accounts <no-rely@meteor.com>",
  verifyEmail: {
    subject: function(user) {
      return "Please verify and active your email";
    },
    text: function(user, url) {
      //console.log(user.profile);
      var username = "\nYour username is: " + user.username;
      var password = "\nYour default password is:" + "123456" + "(Please change           it asap while you login)";
      var greeting = (user.profile && user.profile.empName.firstName) ?
        ("Hello " + user.profile.empName.firstName + ":") : ("Hello," + "\n");

      greeting = greeting + username + "\n" + password + "\n" + "\n" + "To verify your account email, simply click the link below.\n" + "\n" + url + "\n" + "\n" + "Thanks.\n";

      return greeting;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the exact error message and which file and piece of code is causing the error? Also, `Accounts.emailTemplates` can only be run on the server: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_emailtemplates

Comment: I am using accounts-ui which provides a default GUI for users managements like sign in and registration and other stuff. When I click on forgot password on this GUI , I receive error message.

Comment: You need to set up Meteor to send emails. It won't do it automatically for you: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/email

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I think I have set up Accounts.emailTemplate on server so that  verify email function already works.But I am not able to use this reset password function work yet. Please help thanks         'Meteor.startup(function () {
  process.env.MAIL_URL = 'URL set up wit mailgun.org';
});'

Comment: `Accounts.emailTemplate` is nothing more than HTML and a little bit of JavaScript. It doesn't do anything in terms of actually setting Meteor up to send emails. Follow the documentation that I posted in the link above to set up email or go search around for a Meteor email setup tutorial. Meteor can send email using the `email` package or you can configure it to use an email service like `mailgun`, `mailchimp`, `mandrillo`, etc

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think I have configure  Accounts.emailTemplate appropriate as I am able to receive registration confirmation emails. the service I am using is mailgun. But not so sure why forgotpassword function does not work for me.

Comment: Hey JunChen. Did you ever figure this out? I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: resetpassword attr in  Accounts.emailTemplates is what you are looking for.